# Push a segue programatically from a TableView Cell in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, tableview

i am developing a rather simple App with Xamarin at the moment, but i am stuck with one thing: I created a tableView within a UIViewController. The cell rendering is done in an external class: TableSource.cs. A Subclass of UITableViewSource. To handle the row Click i did override Row selected:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight
        //Push another ViewController on top:
        UINavigationController test = new UINavigationController ();
        test.PushViewController (new UIViewController (),true);

    }
```

Works like charm so far. But when i try to push another ViewController on top, to display detailed data about the row, just nothing happens, i don't get any error or exception messages.
I also tried it with custom classes for the Nav. Controller and the view Controller, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just create a new UINavigationController and use it like that.  Instead, you need to wrap your UITableViewController in a UINavigationController when you create the TVC - then in your RowSelected you can use the existing NavigationController to push the new ViewController on the stack.

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight

        // parent is a reference to the UITableViewController - you will need to pass this into
        // your TableSource class.  Every ViewController has a NavigationController property - if
        // the VC is contained in a Nav controller this property will be set.
        parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(new UIViewController(), true);

    }
```

When you create your TableSource, pass in a reference to the TableViewController so that your source's RowSelected method can access the NavigationController.

```
// in your TableViewController, when you assign the Source property
TableView.Source = new MyTableSource(this);

// in the MyTableSource class
TableViewController parent;

public MyTableSource(TableViewController parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
}
```

Now, in your RowSelected method, you can access `parent.NavigationController`

Comment: Okay but how do i reference that navigation controller within code? The view controller where i want to push from is part of a tab bar controller. so i added a navigation controller as a "tab" reference to the tab bar controller, and the view i want to push from as a "root" reference to the navigation controller.

Comment: I am trying:        var root = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
   root.NavigationController.PushViewController(new UIViewController(), true); but i get null pointer exeption

Comment: All UINavigationControllers already have a NavigationController property that will be set IF they are contained within a UINavigationController.

Comment: but how can i access this proptery from tablesource.cs? thanks for your help so far by the way ;) sorry the lightbulb just doesn't turn on at the moment..

Comment: So i solved it like this:    var root = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers;
   UINavigationController navController = (UINavigationController) root.GetValue (0);
   navController.PushViewController(new UIViewController(), true);

Comment: which seems to me like a really dodgy solution isn't there a simpler way to access that nav. controllers property?

Comment: Yes, I already explained this is my comment in the code sample.  You have to pass a reference into your source.  I'll edit my sample to be more explicit.

Answer (score -2):

```
UINavigationController test=new UINavigationController ();
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(test,true);
```

Comment: thats, your create a variable for viewcontroller .then just use default navigationcontroller.pushviewcontroller(variable name,true);

Comment: u can use modal or root view controller too for navigations