# ViewController to ViewController Segue in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I do not want to use button segue to other viewcontroller. I would like to use viewcontroller to viewcontroller segue and use any button with a segue identifier.

Or imagine that I do not have any button in my viewcontroller. I only have tableviewcontroller, once user clicks on any row, then segue happens.

See my code snippet written in native iOS. I have not came across the similar way of segue in xamarin. I have been banging my head against the wall for a while now.

Is there a similar way to achieve same functionality in Xamarin?

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isClicked" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    UserInfoViewController *uVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"isClicked"]) {
     // do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        PerformSegue ("isClicked", sender);
    }

public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        if (segue.Identifier == "isClicked")
        //do what you want
    }
```

Comment: Hello Streamblay,how to create isClicked segue from one viewcontroller to anotherviewcontroller? I could not able to create a segue between vuewcontrollers

Comment: Are asking about presenting a new viewcontroller from the current viewcontroller? For a TableViewController you would follow what they did in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914297/push-a-segue-programatically-from-a-tableview-cell-in-xamarin-ios). Does that help?

Comment: do you have an idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100419/segue-in-xamarin